# How can I update the GPS on screen

Tags: android, gps, android-studio

I follow a tutorial that clicking on a button it call a class that bring all the GPS lat/long information, the thing is that I need it to be call automatically and each certain time and displacement of the device It had to display new values on the screen but it only show the first time. This is what I have:

```
public class GPS extends Service implements LocationListener{

private final Context mContext;

//flag for GPS status
boolean isGPSEnable = false;

// Flag for network status
boolean isNetworkEnable = false;

// flag for GPS status
boolean canGetLocation = false;

Location location;  //location
double latitude;     //latitude
double longitude;   //longitude

// the minimum distances to change Updates in meters
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // Minimun distance 10 meters

// The minimum time between updates in millisenconds
private static final long MIN_TIME_BTW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 MINUTE

// Declaring a Location Manager
protected LocationManager locationManager;

public GPS(Context context){
    this.mContext = context;
    getLocation();
}

public Location getLocation() {
    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        //getting GPS status
    isGPSEnable = locationManager
            .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        //getting network status
        isNetworkEnable = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if(!isGPSEnable && !isNetworkEnable){
            // no network provider is enable
        }
        else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;
            if(isNetworkEnable){
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BTW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, (LocationListener) this);
                Log.d("Network", "Network");
                if(locationManager != null){
                    location = locationManager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if(location != null){
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    }
                }
            }
            // if GPS Enable get lat/long using GPS Services
            if(isGPSEnable){
                if(location == null){
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BTW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("GPS ENABLE", "GPS Enabled");
                    if(locationManager != null){
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null){
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return location;
}

/**
 * Stop using GPS listener
 * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
 */

public void stopUsingGPS(){
    if (locationManager != null){
        locationManager.removeUpdates((LocationListener) GPS.this);
    }
}

/**
 * function to get latitude
 */
public double getLatitude(){
        if(location != null){
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }
    //return latitude
    return latitude;
}

public double getLongitude(){
    if(location != null){
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }
    //return longitude
    return  longitude;
}

/**
 * Function to check GPS/wifi enable
 * @return boolean
 */
public  boolean canGetLocation(){
    return this.canGetLocation;
}

/**
 * Function to show settings alert dialog
 * On pressing Settings button will launch Settings Options
 */

public void showSettingsAlert(){
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle(mContext.getString(R.string.AlertDialog_Tittle));

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage(mContext.getString(R.string.dialog_message));

    // On pressing Setting button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
        }
    });

    // On pressing cancel button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location){
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
```

}

on the main activity

```
public class GPSActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private EditText edTLatitud;
private EditText edTLongitud;
private EditText edTCompass;
private EditText edTDirecc;
private SensorManager sensorManager;
private Sensor compassSensor;

// GPS class
GPS gps;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.gpsactivity);

    edTCompass = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.edTxtBrujula);
    edTDirecc = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.edTxtBrujdireccion);
    edTLatitud = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.edTxtLatitud);
    edTLongitud = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.edTxtLongitud);

    gps = new GPS(GPSActivity.this);

    // Check if GPS is enable
    if(gps.canGetLocation()){

        double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
        double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

        // Print on the screen the coordinates
        UpdateGPSonScreen(latitude, longitude);
    }
    else {
        // can't get location
        // GPS or network is not enable
        // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
        gps.showSettingsAlert();
    }
}
```

thanks in advice

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `UpdateGPSonScreen` only once. If you need constant updates you would call that method everytime within `onLocationChanged(Location location)` but in order for you to do that you would need to refactor a little.